# How to return a value printed by Java to the bash script it is called from?

Tags: java, bash

I have a Java program that prints something using `System.out.println()` . How can I get that output into my bash program? I am trying something like this:

```
$offset = java -jar /path/to/jar/myjar.jar $arg1 $arg2
```

But that line will just give me the following error:

```
0: command not found
```

Comment: `offset=$(java -jar /path/to/jar/myjar.jar $arg1 $arg2)` (notice also no `$` before `offset`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Comment: Apparently `offset` was already set to 0 and so `$offset` literally tries to run a command with that name, with `=` and `java` etc as parameters. Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642